# Eliminar margen horizontal de figure y article en flexbox

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy creando una página y estoy atascado en un parte de la cual no encuentro ninguna solución.

El problema es que quiero colocar los eventos (`article`), debajo del encabezado *Upcoming Events* y al lado de `figure`.

No entiendo por qué los `article` se colocan debajo del figure y en cambio `h2` sí se coloca al lado de `figure`. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```css
  body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans HK', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#events {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: start;
}

#events figure {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #555;
}

article {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #555;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
```

```html
<section id="events">
  <figure><img src="images/soccer_image2.jpg" alt=""></figure>
  <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
  <article>
    <h3>August, 4</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint nisi, quisquam dolor est possimus maxime ipsum, iusto incidunt perspiciatis ea quia natus, repudiandae ullam voluptas. Facilis, vitae fugit harum.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h3>August, 16</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque fugiat laboriosam sint, officiis optio et veritatis. Consequuntur eligendi, architecto, enim, ea quibusdam magni voluptatum, iusto repellendus fugit unde laboriosam deserunt.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h3>September, 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint id et iusto, aliquam consectetur cupiditate nobis tenetur ducimus asperiores sunt, soluta est sit reprehenderit expedita eveniet assumenda vero quis, ex.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Podrías adjuntar una imagen de lo que quieres lograr? Hay varias formas de hacer lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta una capa de contenedores para delimitar las columnas.

Tal y como entiendo tu pregunta, deberías de tener una estructura como esta:

**HTML:**

```
<section class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Cotenido primera columna -->
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <!-- Cotenido segunda columna -->
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* Por defecto ya es row */
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Resto de propiedades css para alinear a tu gusto */
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans HK', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

figure img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.columnFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: start;
}

#events {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ececec;
  display: flex;
  
}

#events figure {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #555;
}

article {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #555;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
```

```html
<section id="events">
  <div class="columnFlex">
    <figure><img src="https://pkf-francisclarkcareers.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/placeholder.png" alt=""></figure>
  </div>
  <div  class="columnFlex">
    <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
    <article>
      <h3>August, 4</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint nisi, quisquam dolor est possimus maxime ipsum, iusto incidunt perspiciatis ea quia natus, repudiandae ullam voluptas. Facilis, vitae fugit harum.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>August, 16</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque fugiat laboriosam sint, officiis optio et veritatis. Consequuntur eligendi, architecto, enim, ea quibusdam magni voluptatum, iusto repellendus fugit unde laboriosam deserunt.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>September, 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint id et iusto, aliquam consectetur cupiditate nobis tenetur ducimus asperiores sunt, soluta est sit reprehenderit expedita eveniet assumenda vero quis, ex.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  
</section>
```